# Migrations via eloquent and problem with drop foregin key

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, migration

I have problem with drop foregin key via migrations. This is my funtion for 'down' or call 'rollback' (this is last created migration file)

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::connection('intranet')
        ->table('flyer_detail', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('flyer_detail_flyer_uuid_foreign');
        });
}
```

As you can see i want drop foregin key from db 'intranet' and table 'flyer_detail'... If i run command `eloquent:migrate:rollback` i can see:

> Rolling back: 2019_10_16_091512_change_flyer_detail_foregin_key_cascade_on_delete
>
> Rolled back:  2019_10_16_091512_change_flyer_detail_foregin_key_cascade_on_delete

So without ANY error. But foregin is still here... Can anybody help with this?

Why is foregin still here? Why is not deleted? I need set foregin checks? Why i not get any exception about this?

Thx.

Comment: It's `flyer_detail_flyer_uuid_foreign` the column name? Can you show how you set that foreign key on the up función?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ No. It is index name. In up function i have same code because that colum already exist and foregin key too but now i need set only cascade behaviour on delete in sql...

Comment: can you show the up method?